# MIT App inventor: My sound player only plays once every 5 seconds

Tags: android, audio

So I'm making a simple drum app but when I click on the Hi-hat it plays but then I have to wait 5 seconds before it plays again. Why is this and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Some more information would be nice, what do you have, what do you want, do you get any errors?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I get no error messages. I want it so I don't have to wait 5 seconds before playing the drum again. And so far I've done 4 drums. However the snare has a shorter waiting time than, for instance, the bass. Is that something to do with it?

Comment: It is very hard to say without any code snippets, or access to the audio files you are using? But my initial thought is that those delays could be because the audio files are that long?